# Register new user from java web application in file releam in payara server

Tags: java-ee-6, payara, java-ee-8

I am creating an enterprise application and I need to add a new user in realm file. what is the best way to register a new user in a realm with the Payara server?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I  think it isn't possible. Use jdbc realm, if it is enterprise application integrate with LDAP or use third party services using OAuth